# Liquibase and spring jpa

Tags: spring, hibernate, postgresql, jpa, liquibase

I'm having problem with deploy postgres on a linux environment though I don't sure it's related.

- Linux version: 9.3.11
- Windows version: 9.5

The error that I get:

```
2016-03-15_19:19:40.478 [http-nio-9090-exec-3] WARN  o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42P01
2016-03-15_19:19:40.479 [http-nio-9090-exec-3] ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - ERROR: relation "rbac_roles" does not exist
  Position: 125
2016-03-15_19:19:40.520 [http-nio-9090-exec-3] ERROR o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet] with root cause
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "rbac_roles" does not exist
  Position: 125
```

On my windows environment table definition created by Liquibase looks as following:

```
-- Table: public.rbac_roles

-- DROP TABLE public.rbac_roles;

CREATE TABLE public.rbac_roles
(
  tenantid character varying(255) NOT NULL,
  id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('rbac_roles_id_seq'::regclass),
  name character varying(255) NOT NULL,
  urlprefix character varying(255),
  CONSTRAINT pk_rbac_roles PRIMARY KEY (id),
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE public.rbac_roles
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

On my linux (the prblematic) environment table definition created by Liquibase looks as following:

```
-- Table: public.rbac_roles

-- DROP TABLE public.rbac_roles;

CREATE TABLE public.rbac_roles
(
  tenantid character varying(255) NOT NULL,
  id serial NOT NULL,
  name character varying(255) NOT NULL,
  urlprefix character varying(255),
  CONSTRAINT pk_rbac_roles PRIMARY KEY (id),
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE public.rbac_roles
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

The Spring Jpa object looks like this:

```
@Entity(name = "rbac_roles")
public class Role implements HasTenantId {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name="roles_seq", sequenceName = "rbac_roles_id_seq")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "roles_seq")
    private int id;
```

...

The Liquibase config looks like this:

```
 <createTable tableName="rbac_roles">
            <column name="tenantid" type="varchar(255)">
                <constraints primaryKeyName="pk_roles" nullable="false" />
            </column>
            <column name="id" autoIncrement="true" type="integer">
                <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false" />
            </column>
            ...
        </createTable>
```

The table rbac_roles created successfully but ID looks diffrent

What I'm doing wrong, why the behavior is different?

Comment: The entity you have posted `RolePermission` is not related to `rbac_role` table. May be, you wanted to post a different entity that is related to `rbac_role` table?

Comment: You are right, thanks,  I have edited the post

Comment: Update: updating to version 9.5 on linux seems the proble, solved (Id still is serial)

Answer (score 0):

In your JPA Annotations you are using a sequence generator, but in your changelog there is an autoincrement type for ID attribute

```
<createTable tableName="rbac_roles">
    <column name="tenantid" type="varchar(255)">
        <constraints primaryKeyName="pk_roles" nullable="false" />
    </column>

    <!-- HERE you specify autoincrement -->
    <column name="id" autoIncrement="true" type="integer">
        <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false" />
    </column>

    ...

</createTable>
```

It is confusing, and I don't know why this code is generating different tables on windows and linux, maybe your postgresql is not the same version ...

Please, fix your changelog and put the following

```
<createTable tableName="rbac_roles">
    <column name="tenantid" type="varchar(255)">
        <constraints primaryKeyName="pk_roles" nullable="false" />
    </column>

    <!-- Removed autoincrement -->
    <column name="id" type="integer">
        <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false" />
    </column>

    ...

</createTable>

<!-- HERE I specify sequence -->
<createSequence sequenceName="rbac_roles_id_seq" incrementBy="1"/>
```

This way, it should generate same table on both systems.

Comment: Thanks! checking it, meanwhile I updated the post with the versions
Linux version: 9.3.11
Windows version: 9.5